# Type of font isn't recognised in itext 7

Tags: java, itext7

```
URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("font/font1.ttf");
byte[] b = PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(String.valueOf(font_path), PdfEncodings.WINANSI);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(b, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
```

Comment: You take an URL, then encode a String representation of the URL using Windows ANSI encoding as a byte array, and then try to read these bytes as a font. Of course those bytes aren't a font, they are an encoded URL string.

Comment: Can you please tell me code it please

Comment: Raj, see @Alexey's answer for example code.

Comment: I can't find a solution

URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("font/alex1.otf"); 
try (InputStream is = font_path.openStream())
 { byte[] bytes = StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(is); 
PdfFontFactory.createFont(bytes, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true); document.setFont(font); } 
It gave me error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.URL.openStream()' on a null object reference. I have alex1.otf file –

Comment: That simply means that the resource could not be found. Make sure the context class loader has access to that resource.

Comment: How can you please tell me?

Comment: that depends on how your code is built.

Comment: I am building simply  as usual we do

Comment: Then put the file where you usually put files to be retrievable as resources via the context class loader.

Answer (score 0):

As explained my mkl in the comments, you have a logical error in the code which has nothing to do with iText - you should fetch the bytes of your resource correctly first.

Here is an example on how to do it:

```
URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("font/font1.ttf");
try (InputStream is = font_path.openStream()) {
    byte[] bytes = StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(is);
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(bytes, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED);
}
```

Comment: URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("font/alex1.otf");
                    try (InputStream is = font_path.openStream()) {
                        byte[] bytes = StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(is);
                        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(bytes, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
                        document.setFont(font);
                    }


It gave me error  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.URL.openStream()' on a null object reference. I have alex1.otf file

Comment: Then it's a problem with getting your file and the url is null. Make sure you are providing correct path and the file is available on classpath

Comment: I have this file but I don't know about class path can you guide me please?

Comment: Please tell me I am badly stuck and I know this file isn't accessible please tell me how to add class path

Comment: Please tell I am stucked

Comment: Try using /font/alex.otf instead of font/alex.otf