# I can access access my font directory in my android app . I read somewhere there is a permission issue or I have to build my app with maven

Tags: java, android, android-studio, itext, itext7

URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("font/alex1.otf");
try (InputStream is = font_path.openStream())
{ byte[] bytes = StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(is);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(bytes, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true); document.setFont(font);
}

It gave me error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.URL.openStream()' on a null object reference. I have alex1.otf file –

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type of font isn't recognised in itext 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094846/type-of-font-isnt-recognised-in-itext-7)

Comment: NO, actually he wasn't parsing correctly. I did correctly and secondly when I build my this font file isn't in app